# Matlab Histogram

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have plotted a histogram (say P(r) for some randon numbers) in Matlab . How can I now get the value of P(r) corresponding to a given value of r? I mean I need the bar height corresponding to a given value on the x-axis of the histogram in MATLAB

Comment: @PeterL. I understand the response to encourage new users to learn how to solve problems for themselves, but keep the responses appropriate. The OP isn't obviously asking for code, a simple answer indicating how to find the solution in the docs is all that is needed.

Comment: @slayton thanks, I got the idea. But who is OP you mention?

Comment: @PeterL. OP-> Original poster

Comment: @slayton thanks, was not familiar with such acronym.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Matlab documentation for `hist`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

> `[n,xout] = hist(...)` returns vectors `n` and `xout` containing the frequency counts and the bin locations.

In other words, `hist` has optional output arguments, which contain the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

See @Oli already answered this as I was creating some example code:

```
%# Generate random data
nPoints = 100;
data = rand(N,1);

%# Calculate histogram
[nInBin, binPos] = hist(data,20);

%#Extract P() from nInBin
P = nInBin / nPoints;

%# X position to look for histgram "height" in
posToLookFor = 0.4;

%# Find closest bin
[~, closestBin] = min(abs(binPos-posToLookFor));

%#Visualize
figure();
bar(binPos,P)
hold on;
plot([posToLookFor posToLookFor], [0 P(closestBin)],'r','linewidth',3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Oli Charlesworth. Your answer is very tidy and understandable. Good job.